# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' IN MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in mvc. I have to display a model dialog box.. but it shows an error like this.. the code should be shown below..

in view

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic dialog">

    </div>
    <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'hi there',
            modal: true,           
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $('#opener').click(function () {
            //Load the CreateAlbumPartial action which will return 
            // the partial view _CreateAlbumPartial
            $('#dialog').load('@Url.Action("PartialTest")',
                    function (response, status, xhr) {
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    });   
        });
    });
</script>
```

in controller

```
 //[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult Test()
        {

            //List<string> category_lst = new List<string>();
            //category_lst = (from r in db.dept select r.dname).ToList();
            return PartialView(db.dept.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Exactly.  'It shows an error like this' what is the error it shows?

Comment: Error is in the title :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add following references to the page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

***Update***

---

In your comment, you are doing it totally wrong. Make your code like following and remove other references.

BundleConfig,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

Layout,

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Comment: <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.3-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="../../Content/themes/base/images/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a mismatch in your IDs for the dialog DIV.

- the HTML uses "dialog-modal"
- the JS uses "dialog"

Try changing the JS to this:

```
    $('#dialog-modal').dialog({
```